# How to run multiple microservices in one jvm

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

**I have around 10 microservices which are spring boot applications, how to run those microservices in one jvm in a single port.**

Comment: Hey Yogesh. I am not sure what your question is. As you know, it is not possible to run multiple applications simultaneously on the same port. So, please clarify what do you want to achieve

Comment: By default spring boot starts embedded tomcat. But you can start tomcat first and then run all your projects inside it

Try this tutorial https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-war-tomcat-deploy

Answer (score 1):

You can change the packaging to war and then run the wars in an app server like Tomcat.

1. Change packaging from jar to war
2. extend SpringBootServletInitializer
3. Mark tomcat dependency as provided

Please find the official documentation here:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto.traditional-deployment